# Условие в SELECT: если a>1000, то a = 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день! 
Есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
          DateTime =  max(DateTime),
          OrderNo,
          ProductNo,
          Value,
          Brand,
          BrandName,
          LinkUp,
          KDF,
          StartDate,
          CompletionDate,
          ID_AVG,
          Consumption = AVG(Consumption) 
FROM
 (....) S1 

            GROUP BY

            OrderNo,
            ProductNo,
            Value,
            Brand,
            BrandName,
            LinkUp,
            KDF,
            StartDate,
            CompletionDate,
            ID_AVG
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы если в выборке **`AVG(Consuption)`** было больше *1000*, то присваивать значение *1000*.
 Как это проще всего реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих задач используется [Выражение CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx)

В вашем случае как-то так:

```
SELECT
      DateTime =  max(DateTime),
       OrderNo,
       ProductNo,
       Value,
       Brand,
       BrandName,
       LinkUp,
       KDF,
       StartDate,
       CompletionDate,
       ID_AVG,
      CASE 
         WHEN AVG(Consumption) > 1000 
         THEN '1000'
         ELSE AVG(Consumption)
      END as Consumption 
FROM (...)
```

Comment: Его можно прям в этот селект ставлять? или надо новым отдельно?

Comment: @lion295 исправил ответ. Можно прямо в этот Select

Comment: да! Спасибо! как оказалось можно и так: 
Consuption = CASE 
         WHEN AVG(Consumption) > 1000 
         THEN '1000'
         ELSE AVG(Consumption)
      END

Но ваш вариант красивее!)

Comment: @lion295 можно еще поменять DateTime =  max(DateTime), на max(DateTime) as DateTime,